# UIScrollView and Autolayout prevent contentview compression

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

In IB I have a view controller that contain a scrollview.

The red view is inside the scrollview

The minimum height of the red view is 504px, so on iphone 4 it should scroll and on iphone >=5 it should extend and layout the buttons to fill the blank.

I set the constraints of the red view to 0 from top, leading, trailing and bottom of the scrollview and also centered horizontally and vertically.
My redview has a minimum height of 504

The blue and green views have equal height

Everything is fine for iphone >=5 but for iphone 4 the red view is compressed to be the size of the scroll view and the buttons are touching each others.

After multiple constraints adjustments I'm wondering if it's even possible to do what I want 100% in IB with autolayout

[image]

[image: iphone 4 !OK]

[image: iphone 6 OK]

Answer (score 0):

You say (emphasis mine:)

"I set the constraints of the red view to 0 from top, leading, trailing and bottom of the scrollview and **also centered horizontally and vertically.** My redview has a minimum height of 504"

First, I can see some redundancy (the bold part).Your redView does not need the vertical constraint since you have already pinned it on the edges of the scrollview and has a defined minimum height.

But this could or not be the cause of the buttons coming closer together, depending on the rest of the constraints.

Have you set vertical space constraints for the buttons?

Comment: I have set vertical space constraints for the blue views (minimum height 12px) And the buttons have 60px height constraints and 0px top and bottom from blue views

Comment: removing the vertical centering of redview and scroll view gave me the result I wanted on iphone 4 but on iphone > 5 the redview doesn't stretch to the bottom of the scrollview

Comment: In a recent similar situation, I opted for making the redView into a "background view". Have you considered that option? What I mean by this is that you can try to put the redView "outside and behind" the scroll view ("above" the scrollView in IB's hierarchical view). Things will be easier to control/follow this way.

Comment: Or you can apply different priorities for your constraints depending on which one you want to "prevail" in scenarios that include conflict resolution.